# Phonegap App directory suddenly contained folders and files with strange file names

Tags: directory, phonegap, phonegap-desktop-app

I am currently working on a mobile app project using PhoneGap. The thing is, the app's size was fairly small, but when I tried to transfer it to my pc, it suddenly went up to 200+GB, which was strange, so I traced the directory and found folders and files with weird characters as file names. I tried searching about it. Sadly, I couldn't find any. I'm not sure if these files are needed or will it affect my app if I delete them.

[Here is a snippet of the folder names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXTxL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is this inside the .apk?

It looks like corrupted data.

PhoneGap is in the process of shutting down. You might try building with an alternative service, such as VoltBuilder (https://volt.build).

Comment: It isn't inside the apk itself since I use the cloud for apk and only upload the www folder and the config.xml file. It's inside the platform folder which leads down to a bunch of subfolders. Should I just delete them?